# How can I detect recycling from within a recyclerView adapter, so I can perform an action before it gets recycled?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a `recyclerview` that contains fields with `editTexts`. When scrolling, the data in the edit texts gets all mixed up or erased due to some functions I use and the views being recycled.
This could be completely solved if I could save my data before the view gets recycled.
How can I detect that happening from WITHIN the adapter?

Comment: Just set `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);` in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method so you never loose your data

Comment: @RutvikBhatt I didn't know that was an option (beginner of course). That solved it so easily! Thank you. Please right it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: A suggestion: You should implement TextWatcher on the EditText and save its value into the model class. So whenever view gets recycled it automatically sets the text in EditText according to the view position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below code in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

so you never lose your data on the scroll.

Comment: This will kill the recyclerview's original nature of recycling the views.

Comment: @GhodasaraBhaumik Yes, In some cases you need to persist your data from recycling. That's why this option is given by the android support library.

Comment: In those cases we can add onEditTextChangedListener to capture all the input event and store them in our object. And also we can check in onBindViewHolder if object has some data than reflect it into editText so that when user scroll down and come back user has still same data available.

Comment: And even if you want to stop your views being recycled than you should use ListView instead RecyclerView.

Comment: @GhodasaraBhaumik Thank you for your Idea add this as your answer so It may help others to do the same. don't forget to add implementation. :)

Comment: This shouldn't be an accepted anwer as is doesn't answer the title!! Others still need a listener when an item gets recycled

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate way to do this is through setting a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and save the text passed on `onTextChanged` to your `RecyclerView` model and retrieve it when you're binding your view again but if you wish to do it when the view id getting recycled, you have to override the [`onViewRecycled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onviewrecycled) method on your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    ...
}
```

Note that in order to get notified of view recycling when recreating the views you also need to set a null adapter to your `RecyclerView`. Here is an example using a fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android RecyclerView adapter has function's called,

onViewAttchedToWindow();

onViewDetachedFromWindow();

onViewRecycled();

Use this function's to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

While setting the data in Views inside **onBindViewHolder()** method use **vh.setIsRecyclable(false);** it will restrict your views to be recycled.

Comment: It will then remove the concept of RecyclerView

Comment: so what?  That option is there for a reason.  I wish we knew about this a few months ago when we implemented one in our app.  I had to help the developer writing it debug why buttons were visible that shouldn't have been.

Comment: You need a solution to your problem so I mentioned one. it may or may not be the best answer so it's up to you to use it or not.